# Capture "yes" and "no" in AWS Connect "Get Customer Input" block

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

This seems like a fairly basic requirement, but how do you capture a simple "yes" or "no" chat response in AWS Connect?

I have created a simple "Confirm" Lex intent which accepts utterances of "yes", "y" and "yeah" but the intent still returns a positive outcome even if the user types "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished by created a bot with 2 intentions, one of "yes" and the other for "no".
[image: intent list]

Add sample utterances for the "yes" intent, for example:

[image: yes utterances]

Then do the same for the "no" intent, for example:

[image: no utterances]

Then use the Get Customer Input block with your bot, adding both the "Yes" and "No" intents to the block, like this:

[image: Contact Flow]

This sample contact flow produces this response, confirming that "no" is recognized, when tested with Amazon Connect chat.

[image: chat test result]